# Create a mechanism to pass in a positive integer and display all the values of the Fibonacci series up to and including the specified value

Tags: php, html, sequence, fibonacci

```
<form method="get" action="Index.php">
        <fieldset>

            <label for="powerof">Fibonacci: </label>
            <input type="text" name="powerof" value="<?php echo $_GET['powerof']; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name='Go' value="Calculate" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php
    $message = 'The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';
    $powerof = 0;
    $max = 5;
    $temp = $max;

    if (isset($_GET['powerof'])) {
        $powerof = $_GET['powerof'];
    }

    if ($powerof > 100) {
        $powerof = 100;
        $message = 'Sorry, your input was too high. I converted it to the maximum value of 100.<br />The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';

    }

    $i = 1;

    for ($i; $i < $powerof; $i++) {
        $max = $max * $temp;
    }

    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;
    $z = $x + $y;

    echo($message);

    while ($z < $max) {

        $z = $x + $y;
        echo($z . "<br />");
        $x = $y;
        $y = $z;
    }
    ?>
```

this is my code and the issue is that if when i enter 1 into the text box rather than it just showing the 1st number within the sequence it shows the first 4 so for 2 it displays 
1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 rather than just 1 2, any ides guys???

Comment: You could remove the whole "powerof" loop and use `**` in PHP 5.6 or `pow` in any other version

Comment: i could but I've used that so i wouldn't know what to do or what to change

Comment: `$max ** $powerof` or `pow($max, $powerof)`

Comment: thanks but i've solved it anyway

Comment: Even so, you should probably still use one of those two

Comment: could you update my work and show me which part i'd insert them into

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at this lines :

```
for ($i; $i < $powerof; $i++) {
    $max = $max * $temp;
}
```

After this loop, the `$max` var is equal to `5^$powerof`, which is not what you want.
Just remove this part and it should work fine.

Also change your test from

```
while ($z < $max) {
```

to

```
while ($z <= $max) {
```

if you want to include the maximum value.

Comment: if i delete that section then the whole thing just stops working I've already tried it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="powerof">Fibonacci: </label>
<input type="text" name="powerof" value="<?php echo $_GET['powerof']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name='Go' value="Calculate" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
$message = 'The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';
$powerof = 0;
$max = 10;
$temp = $max;

if (isset($_GET['powerof'])) {
    $powerof = $_GET['powerof'];
}

if ($powerof > 100) {
    $powerof = 100;
    $message = 'Sorry, your input was too high. I converted it to the maximum value of 100.<br />The fibonacci sequence is: <br />1<br />2<br />';

}

$x = 0;
$y = 1;
$z = 0;
$counter = 0;

while ($counter < $powerof) {
    if ($counter <= 1) {
        $z = 1;
    } else {
        $z = $x + $y;
    }
    echo($z."<br />"); 
    $x = $y;
    $y = $z;
    $counter++;
}

?>
```

this is the working version